# Setting UIMapView delegate to self triggers warning, but works

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit

In my project, I have a MapView that I add annotations to. I need those annotations to have different images, so I use the `- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation` method.  However, for this to work I need the MapView's delegate to be set to `self`.  So I use this line in the `viewDidLoad` function:

```
self.viewMap.delegate = self;
```

This works as expected, however XCode is warning me with this message:

```
Assigning to 'id<MKMapViewDelegate>' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const__strong'
```

I'm guessing that I am not going about this the proper way, and that's why there's a warning.  So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `ViewController` class—which you might consider renaming to something more descriptive—needs to declare conformance to `MKMapViewDelegate` in its interface:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

// stuff

@end
```

Comment: Hi Jim!  (the VC has a name, just didn't bother typing it in the question).  You were right, I forgot the '<MKMapViewDelegate>'.  Thank you!